# How do i create a global object in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, resources, global-variables, application-resource

I have a wpf navigation application. I have an object that i want to access from different pages. Currently, the object is only available from the page that creates it.

Here what I did.

In page A.xaml

I defined in the page like so

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:SerialComm x:Key="SerialCommDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Above method works except the scope is only limited to the page. I want to be able to access the object from any other page.

I use the object in the page like so

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SerialCommDataSource}}" >
    <TextBox x:Name="tbbaudRate" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding SerialPort.BaudRate}" />
</Grid>
```

I want to put the resource in App.xaml so that I can access it anywhere.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Blah;component/Assets/Blah.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <local:SerialComm x:Key="SerialCommDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True" /> <--Error here
</Application.Resources>
```

How do i create a global object in xaml? The object must be able to be edited anywhere and edited values are updated. I read that one cannot create object in code behind and access it anywhere in xaml. So how do i do this in xaml?

Comment: You are probably just missing the `d:` (designtime) namespace.

Comment: sorry for not adding actual error message. and youre right im missing the d:. all good now. thanks and sorry.

Comment: You should still add the error. For future googlers with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is missing the d: namespace